# AppCompat equivalent to "Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I'm working on creating a custom launcher and found this great [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358)

Everything works well as long as I extend my activities with Activity. I'd like to extend my activities using AppCompatActivity but in doing so, I get the following  error:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

So I decided to write my own style:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

This seems to do the trick, however my background is no longer set to the wallpaper of the phone. Instead it is white.

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

I appreciate all tips and hints that might solve my problem, or put me on the right path to solving it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In onCreate():

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    ll.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
}
```

where main is the id of your root layout of your activity.

Comment: But distorts the image.